# How to parse the Arabic as a keyword in json parser iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Anyone know how to parse Arabic keyword as key ,is that possible in iphone?
Is any solution is there?

```
[arr_brand  addObject:[city2 valueForKeyPath:@"additional_attributes.راي بان"]];
```

Comment: use the utf8string encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this one works..you can replace the special characters(*,/,[,] etc) with the arabic ones :

```
-(NSString *)stringUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding withString:(NSString *)params{

return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                             (__bridge CFStringRef)params,
                                                                             NULL,
                                                                             (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&+$,?%#[]% ",
                                                                             CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing your letters to Unicode letters and by a HTML scape character parser.